# Insert css tag in string if partially string was match

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I was trying to replace the Font color if the string inside was partially matching some condition.

example:

```
var font_str = "<FONT color='red'>aaa-1/2</br>bbb-1/3</br>aaa-1/20</FONT>"
var match = 'aaa'
```

if the word before after -x/x was same as the match string, I want to replace the entire word before `</br>` with black font tag

I was trying to use `.replace()` and `RegExp()` but still have no idea how to achieve what I wanted.

```
font_str.replace(new RegExp(match, "g"), "<FONT face='monospace' color='black'>" + match + "</FONT>")
```

result:

```
var font_str = '<FONT color='red'><FONT color='black'>aaa</FONT>-1/2</br>bbb-1/3</br><FONT color='black'>aaa</FONT>-1/20</FONT>'
```

the output should be:

```
var font_str = "<FONT color='red'><FONT color='black'>aaa-1/2</FONT></br>bbb-1/3</br><FONT color='black'>aaa-1/20</FONT></FONT>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
font_str.replace(
    new RegExp(match.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?=[^<]*</?br\\s*/?>)", "g"), 
    "<FONT face='monospace' color='black'>$&</FONT>"
)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPBM2q/1).

Details:

- See [Is there a RegExp.escape function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/3832970), this escapes the `match` value
- See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPBM2q/1). `(?=[^<]*</?br\s*/?>)` is a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `<`  + `<` + an optional `/` + `br` + zero or more whitespaces + an optional `/` + `>` immediately to the right of the current location.

The `$&` in the replacement is the `match` value that was matched (especially useful when you are running a case insensitive regex search).

Comment: Initializing of the variables is shown in the question.